# How can I write a TFSBuild.proj file which runs two batch files in sequence?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have to write a TFSBuild.proj file which only runs two batch files in sequence. I just need to call proj file from build definition and proj file will call two batch file in sequence. All the building will be done by a batch file residing on the build server.

I have a batch file placed on the build server.  The following is the TFSBuild.proj file I have written:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="GetLatest" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">

<Target Name="EndToEndIteration"
  Condition=" '$(IsDesktopBuild)'!='true' "
  DependsOnTargets="$(EndToEndIterationDependsOn)" >
  <CallTarget Targets="GetLatest"/>
 </Target>

  <Target Name="GetLatest">
    <Exec Command="C:\BuildScript\GetFromTFSTask.bat" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="BuildStampVer">
    <Exec Command="C:\BuildScript\BuildTask.bat" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

I am getting an error:

> The command "C:\StampBuild\GetFromTFS.bat" exited with code 3.

I need to run batch file from build server at given path, I am running build from my dev server.

Answer (score 0):

Read this.

http://www.danielfortunov.com/software/$daniel_fortunovs_adventures_in_software_development/2009/05/21/invoking_batch_files_from_msbuild?source=ActivityLog

Update - Sample Code : This sample is your code modified to use the EndToEndIterationDependsOn property to dictate the order of dependent targets MSBuild should invoke when running an EndToEndIteration.  Does this make sense?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="GetLatest" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">

 <PropertyGroup>
  <EndToEndIterationDependsOn>
     GetLatest;
     BuildStampVer
  </EndToEndIterationDependsOn>
 </PropertyGroup>
 <Target Name="EndToEndIteration"
   Condition=" '$(IsDesktopBuild)'!='true' "
   DependsOnTargets="$(EndToEndIterationDependsOn)" >
 </Target>

 <Target Name="GetLatest">
  <Exec Command="C:\BuildScript\GetFromTFSTask.bat" />
 </Target>
 <Target Name="BuildStampVer" DependsOnTargets="GetLatest" >
  <Exec Command="C:\BuildScript\BuildTask.bat" />
 </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, But I am unable to solve my problem. I have added some more info, Can you please look in to it and suggest.

Comment: Does the bat file need a specific working directory?  Have you tried to run it manually yourself? Also, I see that EndToEndIteration performs a CallTarget on GetLatest, but I don't see where you've included the BuildStampVer target in the targets to be invoked.  Shouldn't you put that target in a DependsOn or something?

Comment: Hi Nick, I didn`t have much idea about proj file. I have to write a proj file that should only call these two batch file in sequence. I have written everything in batch file, and batch file is working fine if I run it manually. Please suggest how should I modify my proj file.

Answer (score 0):

Batch exit code 3 is a path error. Are the path references in 'GetFromTFS.bat' correct?  Any relative path references will try to resolve from where the .proj is run.

Answer (score 0):

I never tried your code, but did you tried by calling cmd /c :

```
 <Target Name="GetLatest">
  <Exec Command="cmd /c C:\BuildScript\GetFromTFSTask.bat" />
 </Target>
 <Target Name="BuildStampVer" DependsOnTargets="GetLatest" >
  <Exec Command="cmd /c C:\BuildScript\BuildTask.bat" />
 </Target>
</Project>
```

I only modified your above example so please adjust cmd /c in your command line properly.

Hope this may work.